# how to use OR operation in jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

```
Elements nextLinks = doc.select(a[href*=https] || a[href*=http]);
```

I need to connect HTTP as well as HTTPS site. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `,` comma separator for that

The following should do

```
Elements nextLinks = doc.select("a[href*=https] , a[href*=http]");
```

Take a look at this: [Selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) and this: [Use selector-syntax to find elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have another doubt. How can we skip the particular link from several links? Is it possible or am i wrong?

Comment: If it worked for you, mark answer as accepted. Try `doc.select("a[href*=https] , a[href*=http]").not("some selector")`

Comment: Was your original question regarding the `OR` answered? If so, mark my answer as accepted and ask a new question regarding the *skip*...